# Replace trailing ".1" to ".2"

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I am assuming you would need a regex for this. The best I could come up with is

```
=REGEXREPLACE(C2, "\.(?=[^.]*$)", ".2")
```

but it only detects the [period in the end](https://regex101.com/r/p78Jcu/1) and the google sheet returns #REF!

Other ways, such as directly changing the cell C2:C5, are also welcomed.

Comment: `=REGEXREPLACE(C2, "\.1$", ".2")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check if the trailing 2 characters from the right are equal to `.1`

- get two chars from the right
- test equality

```
RIGHT(A1,2)=".1"
```

Then, to convert matching values, you can slice off the last two chars (length-2) and append the `.2`

```
LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&".2"
```

All together

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)=".1",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&".2",A1)
```

[image]

---

If you actually want to increment arbitrary values (and not just .1), you can skip the equality check and add `0.1` intermediately

```
=LEFT(C3,LEN(C3)-2)&((RIGHT(C3,2)+0.1)&"")
```

If you have values with more than a single digit, hunt them in an intermediate column so you can use their length to

- add the right power of ten (`.5+0.1`, `.993+0.001`, etc.)
- exclude the right number of chars when appending

If you want a full version parser, consider VBA or passing the column to a more practical language